# Prevent the computer from sending any data

Tags: networking

I'm trying to temporally prevent my computer from sending any packets to any server and also prevent it from responding to any requests such as ICMP or ARP protocols.
In other words, I want that whoever sniffs my network will be unable to see any packets from my computer and also I want to be able to receive packets.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Ehm disable wireless and take the UTP cable out of the system. That will kill any connetion to the outside world. I don't think this is Ubuntu related though as it is now.   Or did you still want to be able to connect to the web? In that case: impossible. Your ISP or VPN provider will always be able to see what you are doing and what you did. And if you want to send something out something needs to come in too and it is always sniffable (if it is useful for the sniffer is another issue ;-) )

Comment: @Rinzwind The question asks about preventing packets from being sent while still allowing the computer to receive packets. The question on how to achieve that on Ubuntu I would consider on-topic here, even though the answer is going to be pretty much the same as for any other Linux distribution. Which packets you can actually see that way is an entirely different question, which isn't Ubuntu specific. And the difference between doing this with a managed switch, an unmanaged switch, and a hub is very relevant to the question and isn't OS specific.

Comment: @Rinzwind As I mentioned I still want to be able to receive data from the internet so disconnecting the cable isn't a solution. And I don't want to surf in the web as you said, I only want to sniff the network without anyone knowing that I'm connected to the LAN

Comment: @NivMoshe What's possible depend on how you connect to the LAN. What access do you have? **1.** WiFi **2.** Port on a hub **3.** Port on an unmanaged switch. **4.** Port on a managed switch (managed by somebody else) **5.** Port on a managed switch (managed by you).

Comment: @kasperd I'm connected through cable, I'm not exactly sure in which way from the ones you've mentioned. All I know is that I'm connected to some kind of box which many Ethernet cables are connected to(including my own) and it's probably connected to the router

Comment: @Rinzwind "asks about preventing packets from being sent while still allowing the computer to receive packets" but the TCP/IP protocol REQUIRES packets to be acknowledged.

Comment: "I'm connected to some kind of box" implies that you may not have permission from the network's owner to sniff packets on their network. If not, cease until you do have permission. Depending upon the jurisdiction, proceeding might get you into trouble.

Comment: @user535733 of curse I have permission to, I'm sniffing my own network in my house, I just not sure what this box is. Might be Ethernet hub that's connected to the router

Comment: @NivMoshe It does matter what the equipment is. Anything you plug into a managed switch can be detected. Even if you plug in just a cable with nothing on the other end there are managed switches which can measure how long the cable you plugged in is.

Comment: @kasperd But it doesn't really matter, I don't mind if the ISP or the network owner will be able to know that I'm connected to the network using the switch, all I want to do is to prevent my computer to send any data so that everyone that'll sniff the network won't see any traffic coming out of my computer.